# Images in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I use Vscode to edit my markdown file. I try to inerst a image from my github to the markdown file. Here is what I do:

```
![comparison](https://github.com/lyb1234567/CS_Self_Study/blob/master/Data%20Structre%20and%20Algorithm/Complexity/image/Comparison.png)
```

But it seems that it doesn't show the image that I want on github. Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

Comment: maybe the url returns 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On VSCode, images are not downloaded from Web by default because of security concerns.
[image: VSCode screen]

A preferable way is to use the local path to the image. Since your images are already in the repository, that should be fine.

```
![comparison](Data Structre and Algorithm/Complexity/image/Comparison.png)
```

You might want to adapt the path to the location of the markdown file.

Comment: Hi, I know that images are not downloaded from Web, but my problem is that after I insert  the link (where I put the image on my github ) and push to github, my github doesn't show the image i want

Comment: Did you try with the link of the raw format image ? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lyb1234567/CS_Self_Study/master/Data%20Structre%20and%20Algorithm/Complexity/image/Comparison.png